# Can't find a site column that DOES apparently exist

Tags: development, content-type, column

Well I've deployed a site column from my xml definition and upto now it's been fine. I then checked my content type (after some unexpected errors) and it's removed itself from the content type and is nowhere to be seen in site columns. I then tried to create the column again through the UI (after numerous deployment attempts) but it says it already exists!?

My question is - where can I find it or how can I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some third-party tools (such as SharePoint Manager on CodePlex - http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438) that can help you find your site column and delete it.  Using SPM is probably going to be simpler for you than trying to find it in code (and since this seems to be a one-off issue).

Comment: Thanks a lot John, appreciate your answer, I'll give it a go.

Comment: This is a genius bit of kit this tool John! Thanks again; all sorted.